# Unexpected behavior of fstream binary write/read, unable to read valid values from file

Tags: c++, pointers, binary

To write to file, I use the following function:

```
void writeDBToFile_BinaryMode(std::vector<structDB::citizen> dataBase,
        std::string fileName) {

    std::fstream fileToWriteTo;

    fileToWriteTo.open(fileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    for (auto &citizen : dataBase) {
        if (citizen.fullName == dataBase[dataBase.size() - 1].fullName
                && citizen.address.street
                        == dataBase[dataBase.size() - 1].address.street
                && citizen.address.houseNumber
                        == dataBase[dataBase.size() - 1].address.houseNumber
                && citizen.address.flatNumber
                        == dataBase[dataBase.size() - 1].address.flatNumber
                && citizen.age == dataBase[dataBase.size() - 1].age
                && citizen.gender == dataBase[dataBase.size() - 1].gender) {

            std::string currentCitizenEntry = citizen.fullName + ';'
                    + citizen.address.street + ';'
                    + std::to_string(citizen.address.houseNumber) + ';'
                    + std::to_string(citizen.address.flatNumber) + ';'
                    + citizen.gender + ';' + std::to_string(citizen.age);

            unsigned short int sizeOfLine = currentCitizenEntry.size();

            fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeOfLine),
                    sizeof(sizeOfLine));

            fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentCitizenEntry),
                    sizeof(currentCitizenEntry));

        } else {
            std::string currentCitizenEntry = citizen.fullName + ';'
                    + citizen.address.street + ';'
                    + std::to_string(citizen.address.houseNumber) + ';'
                    + std::to_string(citizen.address.flatNumber) + ';'
                    + citizen.gender + ';' + std::to_string(citizen.age) + '\n';

            unsigned short int sizeOfLine = currentCitizenEntry.size();

            fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeOfLine),
                    sizeof(sizeOfLine));

            fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentCitizenEntry),
                    sizeOfLine);
        }

    }

    fileToWriteTo.close();

}
```

And to read from file, I use this function:

```
void readDBFromFile_BinaryMode(std::vector<structDB::citizen> &dataBase,
        std::string fileName) {

    std::ifstream fileToReadFrom;

    fileToReadFrom.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);

    while (!fileToReadFrom.eof()) {
        unsigned short int sizeToRead;

        fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeToRead),
                sizeof(sizeToRead));

        std::string currentLine;

        fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentLine), sizeToRead);

        std::cout << sizeToRead << std::endl;
        std::cout << currentLine << std::endl << std::endl;

    }

    fileToReadFrom.close();
}
```

The following function are used in context of:

```
    libdb::writeDBToFile_BinaryMode(dataBase, "writetofilebinary.txt");

    libdb::readDBFromFile_BinaryMode(dataBase, "writetofilebinary.txt");
```

However, output of the read function is not an expected valid value that was written to the file, but semi-correct data mixed with "junk" data, such as:

```
0
Uɥ[ownsend;Highland Drive;5;156;Female
```

And at the end of execution, error is returned:

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted
```

Exactly what is preventing my code from running in expected way?

Comment: ```fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeOfLine), sizeof(sizeOfLine));``` what are you trying to achieve here? Why you don't use ```ostream::operator<<()```?

Comment: This project is an academic tasks with specific requirements. I implemented the method described by you in other function, which works. Write function I mentioned in my question is supposed to write binary data to file with ostream.wire() by the design of the task. (comment re-posted because of accidental deletion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Final functions I used are partly based on Suthiro's code.

Here they are. Write:

```
void writeDBToFile_BinaryMode(std::vector < structDB::citizen > dataBase,
  std::string fileName) {

  std::fstream fileToWriteTo;

  fileToWriteTo.open(fileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

  for (auto & citizen: dataBase) {
    std::string currentCitizenEntry = citizen.fullName + ';' +
      citizen.address.street + ';' +
      std::to_string(citizen.address.houseNumber) + ';' +
      std::to_string(citizen.address.flatNumber) + ';' +
      citizen.gender + ';' + std::to_string(citizen.age);

    size_t sizeOfLine = currentCitizenEntry.size() + 1;
    char lineTermination = '\0';

    fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast < char * > ( & sizeOfLine),
      sizeof(sizeOfLine));

    for (auto & citizen: currentCitizenEntry) {
      fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast < char * > ( & citizen),
        sizeof(char));
    }
    fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast < char * > ( & lineTermination),
      sizeof(char));
  }
}
```

And Read:

```
void readDBFromFile_BinaryMode(std::vector < structDB::citizen > & dataBase,
  std::string fileName) {

  dataBase.clear();

  std::ifstream fileToReadFrom;

  fileToReadFrom.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);

  while (!fileToReadFrom.eof()) {
    size_t sizeToRead; // note the size_t

    fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast < char * > ( & sizeToRead),
      sizeof(sizeToRead));

    char * buffer = new char[sizeToRead];

    fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast < char * > (buffer), sizeToRead);

    std::string currentLine {
      buffer
    };

    delete[] buffer;

    unsigned int currChar = 0;

    while (currentLine[currChar] != '\0') {

      structDB::citizen citizen;

      while (currentLine[currChar] != ';') {
        citizen.fullName += currentLine[currChar];
        currChar++;

      }

      currChar++;
      while (currentLine[currChar] != ';') {
        citizen.address.street += currentLine[currChar];
        currChar++;
      }

      std::string numberTemp;

      currChar++;
      while (currentLine[currChar] != ';') {
        numberTemp += currentLine[currChar];
        currChar++;
      }

      citizen.address.houseNumber = std::stoi(numberTemp);
      numberTemp = "";

      currChar++;
      while (currentLine[currChar] != ';') {
        numberTemp += currentLine[currChar];
        currChar++;
      }

      citizen.address.flatNumber = std::stoi(numberTemp);
      numberTemp = "";

      currChar++;
      while (currentLine[currChar] != ';') {
        citizen.gender += currentLine[currChar];
        currChar++;
      }

      numberTemp = "";

      currChar++;
      while (currentLine[currChar] != '\0') {

        numberTemp += currentLine[currChar];
        currChar++;
      }

      citizen.age = std::stoi(numberTemp);

      dataBase.push_back(citizen);

    }

    fileToReadFrom.peek();
  }

  fileToReadFrom.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a `std::string*` to `char*` in `fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentCitizenEntry), sizeof(currentCitizenEntry));`. This is just wrong. The right way is `fileToWriteTo.write(currentCitizenEntry.c_str(), currentCitizenEntry.length());`
The same goes for reading `fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentLine), sizeToRead);`. You are to read to a temporary buffer and then build `std::string` from that buffer.

This compiles and should work, however, not tested:

```
void writeDBToFile_BinaryMode(std::vector<structDB::citizen> dataBase,
        std::string fileName) {

    std::fstream fileToWriteTo;

    fileToWriteTo.open(fileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    auto citizenCount = dataBase.size();
    auto ii = 0u;

   for (auto &citizen : dataBase) {
        std::string currentCitizenEntry = citizen.fullName + ';'
                + citizen.address.street + ';'
                + std::to_string(citizen.address.houseNumber) + ';'
                + std::to_string(citizen.address.flatNumber) + ';'
                + citizen.gender + ';' + std::to_string(citizen.age);
       
        //this way is much better to handle the last entry in the database          
        if (citizenCount - 1 == ii++)
            currentCitizenEntry += '\n';

        //std::string size() always return size_t, not an unsigned short int. Narrowing conversion is dangerous here.
        size_t sizeOfLine = currentCitizenEntry.size();

        fileToWriteTo.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeOfLine), 
                sizeof(sizeOfLine));
        // note that there is no reinterpret_cast anymore
        fileToWriteTo.write(currentCitizenEntry.c_str(), 
                currentCitizenEntry.length());
    }
}
    
void readDBFromFile_BinaryMode(std::vector<structDB::citizen> &dataBase,
        std::string fileName) {

    std::ifstream fileToReadFrom;

    fileToReadFrom.open(fileName, std::ios::binary);

    while (!fileToReadFrom.eof()) {
        size_t sizeToRead; // note the size_t

        fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&sizeToRead),
                sizeof(sizeToRead));
        
        // in your variant you overwrited the std::string object with your data
        // which leads to memory corruption
        //fileToReadFrom.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&currentLine), sizeToRead);
        
        // allocate a buffer
        char* buffer =  new char[sizeToRead];
        // read to buffer
        fileToReadFrom.read(buffer, sizeToRead);
        // build the std::string from buffer
        std::string currentLine{buffer};
        
        std::cout << sizeToRead << std::endl;
        std::cout << currentLine << std::endl << std::endl;
        //free memory for buffer
        delete[] buffer;
    }

    fileToReadFrom.close();
}
```

Also, if you are not obliged to use `read` and `write` functions, I'd suggest to move to the `operator<<()` and `operator>>()`.

Comment: Solution works to a degree. It does read till the end of the file and does output correct data, however not without noise. Any ideas why it might appear?

Comment: `Adonis Hollyn Braun;Laurel Street;38;192;Male;51
Adrienne Cerise Holmes;Valley View Drive;18;201;Female;81
1

Ahmed Judd Jennings;Route 41;25;139;Male;1
le;51
Alexia Kaitlin Heath;West Street;34;129;Female;33
Andrew Elein Crane;8th Avenue;33;109;Male;68
e;33
Aniyah Tanner Parks;Morris Street;13;99;Female;18
Ariel Shane Ingram;Valley View Drive;23;163;Male;10
Briana Beck Bean;Meadow Street;31;5;Female;4
ale;10
Brianna Michael Potts;Court Street;14;23;Female;15

15

Ciara Arden Kelley;Cedar Lane;22;191;Female;42

15

Cohen Kathryn Marks;Windsor Drive;45;45;Male;61
15`

Comment: Comments obviously do not preserve formatting, but it is easy to see what I am talking about nevertheless. And to be clear, I did remove the size of line output

Comment: I fixed a bug in ```if (citizenCount - 1 == ii++)``` line. Please try this version, and if it does not work, please, provide a reproducible example and clarify what does the "noise" mean.

Comment: Output uploaded here: https://pastebin.com/3excmQa9.

I used the functions you provided, but before that I used database output function for clarity. 

And to be clear, data contained in the database is not real.

Comment: Okay, i see that there were additional symbols in the output. But to debug one does need reproducible example, i.e. input. Or you can wait, perhaps someone will point to a bug in my code.

Comment: You can see the input before the output of the function you provided. To make it even more clear, I am attaching the structs I wrote: https://pastebin.com/mQMDsUUZ